# How to get index position of clicked element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the index value of a particular element that is clicked on from a for loop array. What i would like to do is then use this index value and pass it to a variable called indexValue which will then determine a specific div to show. The div it will show will be the one with the same index value that was passed to the variable. I hope this makes sense, I am just not to sure how to achieve this?

The markup would be something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
   display: none;
}

.show {
   display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

    var indexValue: //Get index value from clicked element
    var test = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

    test[indexValue].classlist.add('show');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put your eventListener in a closure that takes a parameter from your loop. The alert is only so that when you click it in the fiddle you can see the result of the index

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {    
    button[i].addEventListener('click', ((j) => {         
    return function() {
      alert(j)
    }
  })(i))
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbpw61ur/20/

Comment: thanks very much for this, im new to javascript so getting my head around it still. Will need to read up on closures and how they work but this is indeed what i am looking for.

Comment: Basically you return a function that takes a variable from an external scope. So first, I create and call a function (j) => {}, (that's a basic function with the => as syntactic sugar), This function returns a second function that takes the externally scoped variable. This returned second function is the event handler. If you like it, please mark this as the solution